# Cakephp saving data with validation isUnique

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to save data with field that has validation isUnique rule but having issue when trying to update via below method.

```
$this->Model->id = 1; 
$this->Model->save($this->data);
```

If I do above, this generates validation error saying I'm only allowed to have unique value but I'm trying to update this instead.

Is there a way around this issue?

Comment: what happens if you pass the id in the data array along?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks ok to me; Cake will attempt to update a record with the primary key of `id` when it's manually set like that.

Do a search in your table with the supposedly "unique" data; and see if any other result can be found. It's possible you have duplicate data that was in use before you introduced the `isUnique` validation rule.

Are you doing this update within a loop?

You could possibly try changing the `on` validation rule in your model to `create`, preventing it from triggering on an update; but I'm not sure that should be necessary; plus you could then `update` a record with duplicate information, defeating the purpose!

```
var $validate = array(
    'fieldName1' => array(
        'rule' => 'isUnique',
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'on' => 'create', // here
        'last' => false,
        'message' => 'Your Error Message'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the id along with the array. Like:

```
$this->create();
$data['id'] = $id;
$this->save($data);
```